# Etwas wurde kein Partizip Perfekt vs. Kein etwas wurde Partizip Perfekt (word order)

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, negation, grammar-style

Why would you say "Zahlen wurden aber keine genannt." instead of "Keine Zahlen wurden aber genannt."? To me it sounds wrong. Or maybe they could have opted for Zahlen wurden aber nicht genannt...

Here's the whole paragraph, for context:

Das aserbaidschanische Außenministerium hingegen erklärte, die Soldaten hätten Autos kontrollieren wollen, die mutmaßlich Waffen in Bergkarabachs Hauptstadt Stepanakert transportierten, und seien unter Beschuss geraten. Dabei habe Aserbaidschan ebenfalls Verluste erlitten, hieß es. Zahlen wurden aber keine genannt.

The whole article is available here: https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/berg-karabach-117.html

Answer (score 1):

> Keine Zahlen wurden aber genannt.

This sentence is wrong, because the *aber* is in the wrong place, *unless* you somehow want to express, that no number was called "aber" (which is probably never going to be the case).

The usual way of phrasing this would be

> Aber es wurden keine Zahlen genannt (**But** no numbers were stated).

or

> Es wurden aber keine Zahlen genannt (However no numbers were stated)

However, if you want, and as is fitting in this context, to emphasize that it was *numbers* that were not stated, then you can just move the word to the front, as German is quite flexible in its sentence order:

> Zahlen wurden aber keine genannt. (**Numbers** however were not stated.)

Comment: Would still be interested in the difference to "Zahlen wurden aber nicht genannt". I don't know it myself.